# Permanently delete files or folders from a Windows 7 local hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I heard some people mention that files or folders are deleted from local hard drive for good, there is no tracing back. Is that really true?

If not, how do I permanently delete files or folders from it? I have a sensitive data on a local hard drive and I want to make sure nobody will be able to see that file or folders. I am told that would <kbd>ALT + TAB</kbd> delete would be permanently delete for good from the computer?

Comment: What you were told isn't even a valid keyboard shortcut.  You received some extremely invalid information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Permanently** is a very strong word, and there are different ways to look at it.

- Simple file deletion on Windows will send it to the trash bin, where it usually stays for 30 days until it's removed by Windows.
- If you press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> the file will be "permanently" (as far as Windows knows) deleted from windows directly, without going to the trash bin. **However**,
- There are several easy-to-use programs which recover files removed from the trash bin. This is possible because when a file is deleted by windows, one way to see it is that it was removed from the file index, but it's still recorded in the hard drive.
- The next step to "more-permanent" deletion would be writing a new file on the same allocated space, but that's not something you easily control. Another option would be formatting the disk.
- Formatting **might** permanently delete the file, or not. The same programs mentioned above usually have tools to recover formatted disks, and they generally work, even if not completely, but some files are restored.
- Even if these programs aren't able to recover the file, there's always the possibility that an expert could try to recover it using more advanced techniques, which is what sometimes happen in forensic analysis of criminal investigations.
- AFAIK, the only 100% guaranteed way to delete a file is physically destroying the hard drive. Open it up, tear it apart, break it into pieces, burn it in hell's fire. That should do it.
- Unless of course it was ever replicated online (by email or online folders services, like Google Drive, SkyDrive, DropBox, etc. If so, it's beyond your reach).

Comment: So you mention Shift + Delete  you say the file will be permannelty deleted from windows directly ? Would someone like an expert or IT person be able to recover them ?

Comment: read all the bit after the word **However**

Comment: @PROBERT - Yes; It is extremely easy to recovery files marked as deleted from almost any system drive.

Comment: As @Tetsujin said, read the other topics. I used quotation marks because as far as Windows knows, the file doesn't exist anymore, but it can be easily recovered with 3rd party softwares.

Comment: The utility "heidi eraser" (and several others) lets you fill a file with zeros before deleting it, making it severely more difficult to recover on regular hard disks. Secure deletion on SSD is harder to pull off.